# With this RefundTransaction operation, why is my Transaction ID invalid?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to test refunds in the Paypal Sandbox, but I'm getting a confusing response; `The transaction id is not valid.`

I've managed to confirm the following:

- I'm passing in the transaction ID that I get from the `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TRANSACTIONID` of  `GetExpressCheckoutDetails`.
- The Transaction ID is not being modified in between getting it from `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` and passing it in `RefundTransaction`.
- This happens regardless of whether or not I pass `INVOICEID`.
- The `PAYMENTACTION` of `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` for this was `Sale`.

Am I making any obviously incorrect assumptions here? Does it have anything to do with this being a Sandbox order (Doubtful)? Am I getting the Transaction ID from the wrong source?

Just in case any details are needed, I'll leave the full response...

```
{
  "TIMESTAMP": "2014-01-06T18:15:35Z",
  "CORRELATIONID": "cb90afac455c",
  "ACK": "Failure",
  "VERSION": "109",
  "BUILD": "9138168",
  "L_ERRORCODE0": "10004",
  "L_SHORTMESSAGE0": "Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See 
                      additional error messages for details.",
  "L_LONGMESSAGE0": "The transaction id is not valid",
  "L_SEVERITYCODE0": "Error",
  "REFUNDSTATUS": "None",
  "PENDINGREASON": "None"
}
```

And the fields/values of the RefundTransaction call itself... (Redacting credentials even though it's sandbox)

```
{
  "METHOD": "RefundTransaction",
  "TRANSACTIONID": "30888131YM063371A",
  "USER": "[redacted]",
  "REFUNDTYPE": "Partial",
  "CURRENCYCODE": "USD",
  "REFUNDSOURCE": "any",
  "AMT": 57.21,
  "PWD": "[redacted]",
  "SIGNATURE": "[redacted]",
  "VERSION": 109
}
```

EDIT: (May post as an answer if Robert doesn't update his answer after a while, since he deserves credit for this)

PayPal_Robert noted that in my `SetExpressCheckout` call, I was setting the recipient to the actual account that payments would be going to with the live API when - since this is Sandbox - I should have been sending it to the `-facilitator` account.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any transactions with that transactionID in the sandbox environment - across all accounts either. I suspect it's getting mangled somewhere.

The only thing I found for the same API caller is an order with transactionID O-072365850X147461B, created on the 2nd of January.

Can you re-create the entire flow, including creating a fresh transaction and try with that?
If you still run into issues, please file a ticket with us at https://paypal.com/mts (24x7) or shoot me an email (address in profile, I only work GMT however.)

Comment: Created a new flow, manually pulled the transaction ID straight from the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response, and it's still not working. I've emailed you the full details (And will update my question if any of them turn out to be relevant). Take as much time as necessary.